# How to center a frame with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, centering

I searched a lot about how to center a frame with Tkinter and Python 3.8.

I wrote a code where 4 buttons are in a frame but I don't know how to center the frame in the window. I tried several methods like `grid_propagate(0)`, `grid(sticky="")`, `pack(expand=True)`, `...`
But nothing works then.

I am sharing my most recent code there. I hope you can help me.

```
window = Tk()
frame = Frame(window)
button1 = Button(frame, text="Button 1")
button2 = Button(frame, text="Button 2")
button3 = Button(frame, text="Button 3")
button4 = Button(frame, text="Button 4")

button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button3.grid(row=1, column=0)
button4.grid(row=1, column=1)
frame.grid_propagate(0)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me

> Here is the code

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
frame = Frame(window)
button1 = Button(frame, text="Button 1")
button2 = Button(frame, text="Button 2")
button3 = Button(frame, text="Button 3")
button4 = Button(frame, text="Button 4")

button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button3.grid(row=1, column=0)
button4.grid(row=1, column=1)
frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor="c")

window.mainloop()
```